# Does mongodb have an option to write-protect a document once created?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am developing an ordering system using mongodb as my database. I would like to set my order documents as read-only once they are created so that they cannot be edited once saved to the database. Do you know if mongo has such a capability?

I have searched google and have read the mongo documentation but have not found any reference to this capability so far. I am hoping that the option does exist and that it is simply that noone has written about it until now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that option doesn't exist. Your code should be responsible for making a system audit-safe at the application level, not a lower level technology.

A key problem with 'preventing modification' is that it's unclear what that means, exactly. For instance, changing a data type or data structure during a migration (say from `price : 23.4` to `price : { value : 23.4, currency : 'USD' }`) doesn't constitute a *logical* modification, but it sure is on the database level.

Comment: Thanks mnemosyn for the prompt response. I was hoping I could control this at the database level. Do you have any suggestions how I could handle this with application code? My application is web-based, I am using node.js with express.js

Comment: In a previous project, we had a simple rule: do not perform any update queries on the audit collections, ever - except migration tools. Code was reviewed and had a simple data access layer that would verify that the logged in user had access to that particular document. If the document was one of the locked types, the access layer wouldn't allow it. In the end, this is more about company processes, because an admin could still log on to the console and delete a document. Regular backups should be a cornerstone, because there's many more threats than malevolent or accidental code issues.

Comment: Thanks mnemosyn. Here is a little more background about my application. My ordering system has several document schemas (using mongoose), one of which is the order schema to create the order documents. This order schema is referencing (not embedding) several fields from other schemas to import information like products, customer, etc. When first creating the document, the model will import the data from the referenced fields. However I do not want the document to import the referenced fields again if someone accesses the document at a later time.

Comment: For example, imagine that CustomerA places an order. The order is created with the customer name as it is at that moment (CustomerA). CustomerA then decides to change his name to CustomerB. I then decide to check the order for whatever reason. What I would like to avoid is mongo importing the referenced data once again and updating the customer name in the order to the new name (CustomerB). Instead the document should display all fields as they were saved, using the old name (CustomerA).

Comment: To be honest, I have not tested this scenario, so it may be that this is already the default behaviour. But as per my initial question, I was looking for an option in mongo that explicitly locked my documents.

Comment: Don't - copy the data, including customer name, address, product details, etc. Versioned referencing isn't good enough...

Comment: Hi mnemosyn, so you suggest to embed the data instead?